# Modifying Android apps from github

Tags: android, github, import, apk

I'm using the apps on this repository for doing application analysis. The available APks are crashing or cant be installed on the table that I'm using for testing.
https://github.com/fgwei/ICC-Bench
In order to run the apps of my tablet, I need to make some tiny modifications such commenting out some lines, or changing sdk version in the manifest file. Where the source code of these APKs is available, but in order to do the modifications, I create a new project  of Android studio, then copy and paste the code. This manual process is really time consuming, so is there any way for importing the apps into Android studio??? because seems the projects (Android APKs) haven't exported in way allows them to be imported again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps for a cloning Github project in Android studio

1. Select a **VCS** menu from the menu bar.
2. Select **Checkout from Version Control**-> **Github**
3. GOTO Github Project and click on **Clone or download** button and copy url
4. GOTO Android studio and paste url in **Git repository url** and if you want select parent directory and the directory name
5. click on clone button